# Could someone help me draw the Curly bracket for the tabular like this?

Tags: tables, brackets

[image]

Hi guys, I am trying to draw curly bracket like this by using \multirow command but i can't enlarge the curly bracket, can someone help me out?

Here is the commands:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ r m{2pt} c |c |c |c |c |}
&\multicolumn{1}{ c }{}&\multicolumn{1}{ c }{} &\multicolumn{4}{ c }{\texttt{\tabincell{c}{Element\\numbers($\ve$)}}} \\
&\multicolumn{1}{ c }{}&\multicolumn{1}{ c }{} &\multicolumn{4}{ c }{$\overbrace{\,\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad}$} \\[-5pt]

& \multicolumn{1}{ c }{} &\multicolumn{1}{ c }{}& \multicolumn{1}{ c }{1}& \multicolumn{1}{ c }{2}& \multicolumn{1}{ c }{3}& \multicolumn{1}{ c }{4} \\ \cline{4-7}
\multirow{4}{*}{\texttt{Local node numbers($a$)}\hspace{-8pt}} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\left.\left\{ \right.\right.\hspace{-10pt}$}
   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 8 \\ \cline{4-7}
 & & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 6 \\ \cline{4-7}
 & & 3 & 8 & 4 & 5 & 5 \\ \cline{4-7}
 & & 4 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 7 \\ \cline{4-7}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show your best attempt?

Comment: *At least* provide code that would construct an ordinary table in a specific `\documentclass`. Recreating something from scratch shouldn't be left to the community.

Comment: $\big\lbrace\Big\lbrace\bigg\lbrace\Bigg\lbrace$

Comment: What are the commands `\ve` and `\numbers`?

Comment: There must be a clearer way to explain this information. Unless you are required to use this layout against your will, you might want to read the documentation of the booktabs package and see if you come up with something easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just out of curiosity and for fun on how to draw the image shown by the OP. This is an attempt via homemade `tikzmark`, `brace` decoration from `tikzlibrary` with related macros like `link` and `sidelink`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,array,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand\tikzmark[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=2pt] (#1){#2};%
}
\newcommand\link[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=1pt}] 
(#1.north west)--(#2.north east) node[above=5pt,midway,text width=2cm,align=center]{#3};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand\sidelink[4]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,raise=1pt,mirror}] 
(#1.west)--(#2.west) node[left=0.3cm,midway, align=center](#3){#4};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\def\cwidth{0.5cm}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{c C{1.5cm} c |C{\cwidth}|C{\cwidth}|C{\cwidth}|C{\cwidth}|@{}C{0pt}@{}}
                         && \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tikzmark{b}{1}}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tikzmark{}{2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tikzmark{}{3}}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tikzmark{e}{4}}\\[1ex]\cline{4-7}
\tikzmark{aa}{1}&&\tikzmark{b1}{1} & $0^\star$ & 1 & 4 & 8 & \\  [2ex]\cline{4-7}
2                       &&\tikzmark{c1}{2} & 0 & 3 & 3 & 6 & \\  [2ex]\cline{4-7}
3                       &&\tikzmark{d1}{1} & 1 & 4 & 5 & 5 & \\  [2ex]\cline{4-7}
4                       &&\tikzmark{e1}{2} & 2 & 2 & 6 & 7 & \\  [2ex]\cline{4-7}
5                       &&\tikzmark{f1}{1}  & 6 & 4 & 5 & 5 & \\  [2ex]\cline{4-7}
6                       &&\tikzmark{g1}{2} & 7 & 2 & 6 & 7 & \\  [2ex]\cline{4-7}
7                       &&\tikzmark{h1}{1} & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5 & \\  [2ex]\cline{4-7}
\tikzmark{bb}{8}&&\tikzmark{i1}{2}  & 5 & 2 & 6 & 7 & \\  [2ex]\cline{4-7}
\end{tabular}

\link{b}{e}{Element \\ numbers ($v$)}
\sidelink{b1}{c1}{}{1}
\sidelink{d1}{e1}{}{2}
\sidelink{f1}{g1}{}{3}
\sidelink{h1}{i1}{aaa}{4}
\sidelink{aa}{bb}{cc}{}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[<-] (cc) -| ++(-1.5,-4);
\draw[<-] (aaa) -- ++(0,-2);
\draw[<-] (i1) |- ++(0.5,-1)node[right,text width=2cm]{Element \\ $1 \le i \le n_{ed}$ };
\node[below] at (bb){($n_{ee}=8$)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: great, are you working on FEA?

Comment: Thanks, I am afraid not, if FEA means Finite Element Analysis.

Answer (score 6):

use `ldelim` from the package `bigdelim`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

    $\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c|c|}
        & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\begin{minipage}[c][10mm][c]{17mm}\begin{center}\texttt{Element} \\ \texttt{numbers($v$)} \\ $\overbrace{\hspace*{17.5mm}}$\end{center} \end{minipage}} \\ 
        & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} \\ \cline{4-7}
        \multirow{4}{18.5mm}{\texttt{Local node numbers($a$)}}& \ldelim\{{4}{.1mm} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 8 \\ \cline{4-7}
        & & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 6 \\ \cline{4-7}
        & & 3 & 8 & 4 & 5 & 5 \\ \cline{4-7}
        & & 4 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 7 \\ \cline{4-7}
    \end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image]